# How to store constants at the class level that can be overriden?

Tags: swift, subclass, class-variables

I want to write the following in Swift:

```
class A
{
    class let x = 0
    func print_class_property()
    {
        print(type(of: self).x)
    }
}

class B:A
{
    overriding class let x = 1
}

class C:A
{
    overriding class let x = 5
}

A().print_class_property() // 0
B().print_class_property() // 1
C().print_class_property() // 5
```

But of course, this doesn’t compile.

Instead, I can demote the class property to a variable instance property that’s overwritten in the subclass initializers, but this **allocates storage for `x` in *every* instance of `A`, `B`, or `C`.** In addition you lose the guarantee that `x` never changes across the lifetime of the object.

**How do I store constants at the class level, that can be shared by all instances of a subclass?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Swift (as for now) cannot have class stored properties *that can be overriden*. But can have class computed properties, which are overridable.

You can write something like this:

```
class A
{
    class var x: Int {
        return 0
    }
    func print_class_property()
    {
        print(type(of: self).x)
    }
}

class B:A
{
    override class var x: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class C:A
{
    override class var x: Int {
        return 5
    }
}

A().print_class_property() //->0
B().print_class_property() //->1
C().print_class_property() //->5
```

---

**ADDITION**

If you do not desire such re-evaluation as noted in comments, you may need to have some another `static` property.

For example:

```
class A
{
    class var x: SomeLargeObject {
        struct My {
            static let obj = SomeLargeObject("abc", 0)
        }
        return My.obj
    }
    func print_class_property()
    {
        print(type(of: self).x)
    }
}

class B:A
{
    override class var x: SomeLargeObject {
        struct My {
            static let obj = SomeLargeObject("def", 1)
        }
        return My.obj
    }
}

class C:A
{
    override class var x: SomeLargeObject {
        struct My {
            static let obj = SomeLargeObject("ghi", 5)
        }
        return My.obj
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the equivalent of making a function call every time the property is accessed?

Comment: True, as well as stored properties.

Comment: i always assumed accessing stored properties simply consisted of dereferencing a pointer or something similar. but the problem is that the value has to be reevaluated each time the property is accessed, for example storing `let  x = SomeLargeObject("abc", 5)` as opposed to instantiating a *new* `SomeLargeObject` each time the property is accessed

Comment: Swift supports class properties. Example: `static var x = 0`. Now I can do: `A.x = 42`. But such properties can't be overridden in subclasses.

Comment: @rmaddy, I know. Maybe my words are a little too short, but _that can be overriden_ is a requirement in this case. `static` properties cannot be overridden.

Comment: It would be best to update the first sentence of your answer to clarify that it doesn't support class stored properties that can be overridden.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks. Your suggestion seems reasonable and I'll update my answer later.

Comment: @taylorswift, in Swift semantics, stored property is a combination of setter, getter and so-called ivar. In simple cases such as `private` properties, Swift generates codes as described as your assumption even in Optiomization leve: none. But to fulfil your requirement _that can be overriden_, the setter needs to be invoked dynamically. When repeated re-evaluation is not desired, you may need to have another `static` property.

Comment: is there a difference between this and using a freestanding variable

Comment: What do you mean by _freestanding variable_? The answer depends on it.

Comment: a variable that is defined outside of the class, and the computed property simply returns that variable

Comment: @taylorswift, then it's nearly equivalent. A slight difference is that the scope of `My.obj` in my code is strictly enclosed in each getter block. Even in the same class (outside of the getter), you cannot access `My.obj`. Similar to the difference between private static properties and global variables.